# Selenium: finding element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

There is nesting:

```html
<div class = "top">
   <div>
      <span class="bottom"> </span>
      <span class="unknown"> </span>
      <span class="bottom"> </span>
   </div>
</div>  
 
<div class="top">
   <div>
      <span class="bottom"> </span>
      <span class="unknown"> </span>
      <span class="bottom"> </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

It is necessary to take the "bottom" elements in blocks one by one, based on the "top", but this entry returns an empty list.

```
for i in range(2):
      elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='top'][" + str(i) "]//span[@class='bottom']") 
      print(elements)
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: The question could have better answered if you can update the question with the actual condition for selecting the `<div class = "top">` instead of using `range(2)`

Comment: What do you want to print? What's the Expected output?

Answer (score 0):

To get `bottom` elements per `top` blocks here you can use this XPath:

```py
for i in range(1,3):
      elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("(//div[@class='top'])[" + str(i) + "]//span[@class='bottom']")
```

Comment: I need go blocks one by one,,,The code then does some block checking and skips it if it doesn't fit.

Comment: OK, please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Why not retrieve all elements and iterate over them instead?

```py
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="top"]/span[@class="bottom"]')
for element in elements:
    if element:  # some invalidating condition
        continue
    print(element)  # success!
```

This way selectors are much more efficient as you onyl need to execute 1 selector rather than N selectors. Also, note that xpath is pretty powerful - maybe you can integrate selection logic in the xpath itself?

See [live xpath tester](http://granitosaur.us/xpath-tester/?html=PGh0bWw%2BCjxkaXYgY2xhc3MgPSAidG9wIj4KICAgPGRpdj4KICAgICAgPHNwYW4gY2xhc3M9ImJvdHRvbSI%2BIDwvc3Bhbj4KICAgICAgPHNwYW4gY2xhc3M9InVua25vd24iPiA8L3NwYW4%2BCiAgICAgIDxzcGFuIGNsYXNzPSJib3R0b20iPiA8L3NwYW4%2BCiAgIDwvZGl2Pgo8L2Rpdj4gIAo8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSJ0b3AiPgogICA8ZGl2PgogICAgICA8c3BhbiBjbGFzcz0iYm90dG9tIj4gPC9zcGFuPgogICAgICA8c3BhbiBjbGFzcz0idW5rbm93biI%2BIDwvc3Bhbj4KICAgICAgPHNwYW4gY2xhc3M9ImJvdHRvbSI%2BIDwvc3Bhbj4KICAgPC9kaXY%2BCjwvZGl2Pgo8L2h0bWw%2B&xpath=Ly9kaXZbQGNsYXNzPSJ0b3AiXS8vc3BhbltAY2xhc3M9ImJvdHRvbSJd#editor#editor)